# Is MSAL compliant with the new RFC 8252?

Tags: azure-ad-msal

Is or will MSAL be compliant with the new [RFC 8252 OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252.txt) best practice?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The native applications for iOS and Android, using the new MSAL Preview library, follows this framework for the Browser handling the authentication flow.  The Windows .NET library, from the documentation, indicates that it is using something similar to a webview.  In iOS, per the documentation:

> Calling the acquireToken method results in a browser window prompting the user to sign in. Applications usually require a user to sign in interactively the first time they need to access a protected resource, or when a silent operation to acquire a token fails (e.g. the user’s password expired). [Azure AD V2 iOS Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-ios)

As for Windows Desktop .Net, that library results in a Window prompt [AAD v2 Windows Desktop Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-windesktop). In Xamarin applications, that will just follow the pattern of the environment, iOS/Android, get the native browser, Windows Desktop will get the Window prompt from the App.